# Pasar variables entre proyectos de una solución

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin.forms

En una solución con dos proyectos: uno Xamarin.Forms y otro Android (Xamarin) necesito utilizar en el primero el valor de una variable generada en el segundo.
He probado con la declaración de la variable como Global, pero no funciona fuera de su proyecto.
Me gustaría conocer cuál es la mejor alternativa.
Tengan en cuenta que no se trata de una variable entre clases de un proyecto sino entre proyectos de una solución.

Comment: Ls solucion es un concepto etereo de tu IDE... vos queres pasar datos entre 2 programas... abria que ver como son los mismos, para ver cual seria tu mejor solucion...

Comment: Preferible que generes un sub proceso (await Task.Run(() => Método que guarda tu variable en el otro proyecto())) dentro del proyecto de Xamarin.Forms que te envié esa variable a algún método de Android(Xamarin) que guarde ese valor en una variable estática que puedas consultar en cualquier momento.

Claro, si tu variable esta en constante cambio, pues el subproceso se debe hacer varias veces, entonces aplica algún bucle.

Comment: Hola! Pues se trata de una variable que se genera como resultado de un proceso en el proyecto Android (Xamarin). Considero irrelevante describirlo con detalles ya que lo importante es que esa variable la tengo que utilizar en el otro proyecto de la solución. Dime si necesitas conocer algo concretamente sobre el proyecto y te lo explico.

Comment: Hola Marcos! Sí, la variable se actualiza cada 100 ms. Pero se genera en el Android (Xamarin). ¿No hay una forma más sencilla de hacerlo? En estos momentos no sé cómo se envía una dato a otro proyecto de la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras mirar la documentación he optado por una solución que funciona. Se trata de utilizar una carpeta del dispositivo móvil para escribir en un archivo de texto el valor de la variable. He probado con los dos proyectos y se puede acceder sin problemas para escribir y para leer.
Para quien pueda interesar este modo de hacerlo lo explico con más detalle.

En una actividad de Android (Xamarin) del primer proyecto escribo el dato en el archivo de texto *memo.txt* del siguiente modo:

Para escribir en el archivo de texto:

```
 string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "memo.txt");
                    Boolean doesExist = File.Exists(fileName);
                    if (!doesExist)
                    {   
File.CreateText(fileName);
                    } 
                    File.WriteAllText(fileName, Convert.ToString(F));
```

Con la clase **File**, si no existe el fichero lo creamos en la ruta *FileName* previamente formada. Esta ruta tiene dos partes: la primera toma la ruta de **LocalApplicationData** en el dispositivo y la segunda es el nombre del archivo de texto "*memo.txt*".
El valor de la cadena que se escribe es "**F**" (variable anteriormente generada por el flujo de la aplicación).

Una vez cargado el proyecto segundo, Xamarin.Forms, recupero el valor escrito en el archivo de texto de esta forma:

Para leer en el archivo de texto:

```
 string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "memo.txt");

  string txt = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

Nueva edición.-

Incluyendo la escritura y lectura del archivo de texto dentro de tareas asíncronas he comprobado que no se produce ningún bloqueo en el dispositivo Android. En Mac aún no lo he probado.
Sería así.

Para escribir:

```
async Task EscribeFrecuenciaFileText (float F)
    {
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "memo.txt");
        await EscribeFrecuenciaFileText2(F, fileName);
        return;
    }
    async Task EscribeFrecuenciaFileText2(float F, string Path)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(Path, Convert.ToString(F));
        return;
    }
```

Y para leer:

```
string txt = "";
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "memo.txt");
            Boolean doesExist = File.Exists(fileName);
            if (doesExist)
            {                
                    txt = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                    return txt;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado lo que parece que es la solución definitiva para mi consulta. Se trata de la propiedad **Properties** del objeto **Application** de Xamarin.Forms. Es posible escribir y acceder a los valores que almacenemos en ella desde cualquier proyecto de la solución. De la siguiente forma:

```
Application.Current.Properties ["id"] = someClass.ID;
```

Y para obtener los valores almacenados:

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("id"))
{
    var id = Application.Current.Properties ["id"] as int;
    // do something with id
}
```

He comprobado el funcionamiento y va muy bien. Es muy rápido y limpio al no provocar ningún bloqueo en el dispositivo incluso con accesos recursivos a intervalos de milisegundos.

Es necesario escribir el valor usando un **Object**. Lo he hecho de esta forma.

Tengo una clase en la que hay una propiedad *FRECUENCIA*.

```
class PropAplic
        {
            private float _FRECUENCIA = 0;
            // Declare a Name property of type string:
            public float FRECUENCIA
            {
                get
                {
                    return _FRECUENCIA;
                }
                set
                {
                    _FRECUENCIA = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Declaro una instacia de esa clase y le doy el valor deseado.

```
PropAplic Pa = new PropAplic();
    Pa.FRECUENCIA = F;
```

Ahora guardo el valor en la propiedad del objeto **Application**.

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["FRECUENCIA"] = Pa.FRECUENCIA;
```

Y para leer el dato en cualquier otro punto del proyecto actual o de otro de la solución:

```
string txt = "";
            if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("FRECUENCIA"))
            {
                txt = Convert.ToString(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["FRECUENCIA"]);
                  }
```

Como se ve, es neceario convertir de *Object* al tipo que se desee puesto que la propiedad queda guardada como *Object*. En ese caso concreto el tipo de la variable *FRECUENCIA* es *float* y se recupera convertida a *string*.

Importante señalar que es muy conveniente comprobar antes de leer el dato que efectivamente existe la clave guardada. Para ello se emplea:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey()
```

Saludos